# Find a and b such that $x^2 + 8x + 7 = (x + a)(x + b)$ for all real values of $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

Find $a$ and $b$ such that $x^2 + 8x + 7 = (x +  a)(x + b)$  for all real values of $x$.

That is what the question states, I think you should factor

Any Ideas on how to begin?

Comment: Why don't you start by expanding right hand side first? Open the brackets.

Comment: $x^2$  + 8x + 7 =$x ^2$+2ab+$b^2$ correct?

Comment: @user360471, no. Expanding gives $x^2+bx+ax+ab=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$.

Comment: 7+1=8 & 1*7=7, Correct?

Answer (score 7):

Expanding $(x+a)(x+b)$ gives $x^2+(a+b)x+ab$. So you want $a+b=8$ and $ab=7$. Can you see any values of $a,b$ that satisfy these two equations?

Comment: Sorry No I'dont, I think it should be a combination of a positive and a negative integer

Comment: You have $a+b=8$ or $b=8-a$. Put it in $ab=7$ and solve for a.

Comment: 7+1=8 & 1*7=7, Correct?

Comment: @user360471, correct.

Comment: @Galc127 Well, this is just going back to the quadratic $a^2+8a+7=0$... We are not more advanced. One way or another this exercise is based on recognizing $-1$ as a trivial root.

Answer (score 3):

By factorization,
$$x^2+8x+7 \equiv (x+7)(x+1) \equiv (x+a)(x+b)$$

$$\therefore \quad (a,b)=(1,7) \quad \text{or} \quad (7,1)$$

Answer (score 0):

This factorisation is equivalent to finding roots $-a$, $-b$ of $x^2+8x+7=0$. Now the *rational root theorem* says that rational roots, if any, are integers, and these integers are divisors of the constant term. Thus there are only $4$ possibilities: $\pm 1,\pm7$. Further, one sees the roots have to be negative, because of the signs of the coefficients.

Indeed, $-1$ and $-7$ are roots, whence the factorisation
$$x^2+8x+7=(x+1)(x+7).$$

Answer (score 0):

> Use $$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a},\quad \textrm{where }ax^2+bx+c=0$$

which gives $x=-1 \textrm{ or } -7$ , so factorize will be $(x+1)(x+7)$.